# Serve Angular app under nginx location path

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm trying to serve an Angular app (dist) inside nginx server. I tried a lot of configurations I found on the web, and should be working, but it is not.

The app is working when I go to `my-site.com/app`, but it not working when refreshing the page after navigate.

`my-site.com/app` it's ok
`my-site.com/app/dashboard` 404
`my-site.com/app/*` 404

So, `my-site.com/app/*` should serve `/var/www/angular-app/dist/index.html` always.

This is the config block I added to the nginx server conf:

```
location /app {
    index index.html;
    alias  /var/www/angular-app/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
}
```

And this is the complete 443 block, maybe it there any problem with `root` and `alias` paths. This config file belong to a Symphony 1.4 application.

```
server {

    listen 443;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;

    set $website_host "stage.my-site.com";
    set $website_root "/var/www/mainproject/web";
    set $default_controller "frontend_stage.php";
    set $symfony_root "/var/www/mainproject/lib/vendor/symfony";

    server_name $website_host;

    root $website_root;

    index $default_controller;

    charset utf-8;

    location /sf/ {
        # path to folder where all symfony assets are located
        root $symfony_root/data/web/;
        expires max;
    }

    location ~ \.php($|/) {

        set $script $uri;
        set $path_info "";

        if ($uri ~ "^(.+\.php)(/.*)") {
            set $script $1;
            set $path_info $2;
        }

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        #fastcgi_pass backend;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $website_root$script;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $script;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
        break;
    }

    location / {

        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires max;
            break;
        }

        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location /app {
        index index.html;
        alias  /var/www/angular-app/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /frontend_stage.php$1 last;
    }

    location /api/ {
      try_files $uri /api_stage.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be a problem with `alias` and `try_files`. Try replacing the `try_files` statement with `if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /app/index.html last; }`

Comment: It works like a charm!! This is a temporal fix? I mean, should I need to make it work if try files?

Comment: Oh, I could find the problem. `try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html =404;` is the correct way, thanks!!